# C++ function : Variadic templates with no arguments

Tags: c++, templates, types, variadic-templates

I am not sure if this question is already answered. But here it goes:

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like

```
template<typename...classes>
void createObject(){

  //pass each type into my template function wich takes one type only.

}
```

I'm really not getting how it exactly works. The reason I can't provide any function arguments is because my template function which should be called within the method only takes one type. This is because it returns an object depending on it's type.

Any suggestion?

Note:
GCC 4.6.2

Comment: can you qualify better what the fuction is supposed to do and what it should return? Do the returned objects have somehow common type between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename...>
struct caller;

template<typename T, typename...Rest>
struct caller<T, Rest...>
{
     static void call()
     {
        create<T>();
        caller<Rest...>::call();
     }
};

template<>
struct caller<>
{
     static void call()
     {
     }
};

//since you've not mentioned the return type, I'm assuming it to be void
//if it is not void, then I don't know what you're going to return, and HOW!   
template<typename...classes>
void createObject(){
      caller<classes...>::call();
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/UHY8n

---

Alternative (a shorter version):

```
template<typename...>
struct typelist{};

template<typename T, typename ... Rest>
void call(typelist<T,Rest...>)
{
  create<T>();
  call(typelist<Rest...>());
};

void call(typelist<>) { }

template<typename...classes>
void createObject(){
      call(typelist<classes...>());
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/cuhBh

Comment: Yes it's suppose to be void. Could you please elaborate on what you are doing exactly.  I realise it becomes recursive. But don't see how.
You seem to declare "call" twice.

Comment: @Sidar: Search metaprogramming in C++; see few examples, as that will help you to *get start with* it, which will make it easier for me to explain that I did. Otherwise, I've to spend a lot of time, typing a mini tutorial here (which I can't do, as I'm in office now).

Comment: Very well then. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the following function to expand the calls:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void swallow(Ts&&...) {
}
```

I'll assume you want to call the following function:

```
template <typename T>
void create() {
}
```

In this case, you'll need a helper function that converts the void `create` to one that returns something, so that we can expand it in the arg-list of `swallow` (if your `create` function is already non-void, then this extra step is not necessary):

```
template <typename T>
int createHelper() {
    create<T>();
    return 0;
}

template<typename... Ts>
void createObject(){
    swallow(createHelper<Ts>()...);
}
```

Edit: instead of the createHelper, we could use a trick with the comma operator:

```
swallow((create(), 0)...);
```

Comment: I take Ts&&... forwards the next type? But this one isn't exactly recursive, is it?

Comment: No, it's not recursive. The point of the arg-list of `swallow` is that it binds to anything (we don't actually do anything with the args, as you can see, the whole call will be optimized out). It's just a simple way to expand template-parameter packs in certain situations.

Comment: I'm not fully getting the concept behind it. But thanks for your input anyways. I've already solved my problem so far. Later on I might come back to this.